# What is the most efficient way to get leaf nodes with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How can one get all the leaf nodes, let's say divs, from the DOM? I am trying to think of an optimal solution, if there's no easy and magical selector for this. I thought of using the "reachedElem.find('div').length == 0" but I am not sure if this is the right direction. Any ideas?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can go with following selector

```
$('div:not(:has(*))')
```

Above selector will select all the DIVs who don't have any children.

Comment: Thanks. Does it also applies if I want to find all divs that are the "last" div element in the tree? I am not sure if I am explaining it correctly. Lets say you eliminate all elements that are not divs from the DOM. Now it would be the same of asking all leafs..

Comment: @Ricardo, any DOM element without children is a leaf.  If you want to only look for leaves under a particular element then first select the element then put eHussain's selector in a .find() method to search all ancestors.

Comment: thanks Soviut, but thats not wat I meant. I mean I want to select "all" divs in the DOM that don't have more "divs" as children. Basically all the lowest level divs..

Comment: Hi Ricardo, then you can try out with following selector "$('div:not(:has('div'))')" .. This will help.. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

If you really want something efficient, avoid the complex `:not(:has(*))` selector:

```
$("div").filter(
   function(index) {
      var isLeaf = $(this).children().length === 0;
      return isLeaf;
   }
);
```

I found out it's twice as efficient as eHussain's suggestion, or even faster.

Comment: One faster way rather than `.children()` is `.find(':first')`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on above short and fast would be

```
$("*").filter(function() {
    return $(this).find(':first').length == 0;
});
```

However above selects `<br>` inside text and other possibly unwanted elements, so one would probably need some filtering inside `children()` like

```
$("*").filter(function() {
    return $(this).children('body,div,span').length == 0;
});
```