# How to find each lowest node in the DOM with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, parsing

How can I use the [selector given in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4602476/844668)

```
$('div:not(:has(*))')
```

to find any lowest-level element in a given block of HTML? For example, if my HTML is this:

```
<P style="">
<SPAN style="font-family:'sans-serif'">More:</SPAN>
<SPAN style="font-family:'sans-serif'">at. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et</SPAN></P>
<ul>
  <li>A list item</li>
</ul>
```

Then I want to return three elements- the spans wrapping "More:" & the lorem ipsum text, and the LI wrapping "A list item".

My current code just grabs page chunks at the div level, which is not granular enough for the generated tag soup I am working with:

```
 function loadElements (guideline) {
  var url = guideline.import + "/input.html",
      text,
      i = 0,
      el;
  console.log("url is " + url)
  $.get(url, function(html) {
      $(html).filter('div').each(function() {
        i ++;
        text = i + "<br/>" + $(this).text();
        $("#source_elements").append(text);
      });
  });
 }
```

I'm not sure how to incorporate the more granular selector here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector just needs to be changed slightly. First grab the `body` tag so that you don't get elements from the `<head>` that you don't need. Then you want to grab any tag (*) that doesn't have any tag (*).

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EDcGN/)

```
$('body').find('*:not(:has(*))');
```