# Regex search leaf nodes of poorly-formatted HTML using Cheerio

Tags: jquery, html, parsing, nodes, cheerio

I have some poorly formatted HTML (such as the one below), and I want to get leaf nodes (without any further children) whose text matches a given regular expression:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>co20140725-ex99_1.htm</title>
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="#ffffff" style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">
  <div>
  <div style="TEXT-ALIGN: left">&#160;</div>
  <div style="TEXT-ALIGN: right">EXHIBIT 99.1</div>
  <div style="TEXT-ALIGN: left">&#160;</div>
  <div style="TEXT-ALIGN: left">
  <div style="TEXT-INDENT: 0pt; DISPLAY: block; MARGIN-LEFT: 0pt; MARGIN-RIGHT: 0pt" align="left">
  <div style="TEXT-ALIGN: center"><font style="FONT-WEIGHT: bold">ANNOUNCES</font></div>
</html>
```

I'm using cheerio, which essentially implements the jQuery traversal API. What I've tried so far:

1. The `:contains` selector doesn't support regular expressions, or even case-insensitive text:

   ```
   var text = $('body').filter(':contains("ANNOUNCES")');
   ```
2. `each`, then the standard JavaScript `match`:

   ```
   $('body').each(function (i, elem) {
     if ($(this).text().match(/announces/i)) {
       var text = $(this).text();
     }
   }
   ```
3. `children`, but it outputs one string that is all the text in the HTML:

   ```
   $('p, b, div, font').children(':contains("string I\'m looking for but this isn\'t case-sensitive like match is")').children().first().text();
   ```

I believe the problem lies in the fact that there are variable numbers of nested children and for some reason I do get all of the elements, but each of them has a bunch of children and I haven't been able to just iterate through them and test the text.

[image: This is what my object looks like]

You can see that there are a bunch of variably-nested elements, and usually `.find()` would work for searching through all elements in the `<body>` but `.find()` and `.filter()` don't work in this case at all.

Any thoughts on how I can regex-search the text in this HTML?

Full example HTML can be found [here](http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1171014/000091412114000351/co20140725-ex99_1.htm).

Answer (score 2):

Once clarified, the question has two parts:

1. [Get only the leaf nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602431/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-get-leaf-nodes-with-jquery/13011902#13011902), that is, those that don't have any children of their own, but contain just the text you're after. This will avoid the problem you were experiences with your third approach using `children`. There are two ways of doing this:

   - the `*:not(:has('*'))` selector
   - selecting all elements (`'*'`) then filtering for nodes that have zero children. This is several times faster than the popular complex selector method.
2. Filter the leaf nodes for those whose `textContent` matches your regular expression.

Here's the code:

```
$('*').map(function() {
  if (this.children.length) return null;
  if (this.textContent.match(/N/)) return this.textContent;
});
```

[Here's the JSBin.](http://jsbin.com/muficuye/1/edit?html,js,console) (Ignore the `window.runnerWindow.proxyConsole` extraneous output; it's a JSBin artifact.)