# How to change font-size of multiple elements using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I need to increment the font-sizes of my elements by 1. I already did this, but the long way.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
<h3 class="heading">
  24px font
</p>
<p class="content">
  12px font
</p>
<span class="footNote">
  10px font
</span>
<button id="upSize">Larger</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.heading {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.content {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.footNote {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
 $("#upSize").click(function() {
    var headingSize = parseInt($(".heading").css("font-size"));
    var contentSize = parseInt($(".content").css("font-size"));
    var footNoteSize = parseInt($(".footNote").css("font-size"));
    headingSize = headingSize + 1 + "px";
    contentSize = contentSize + 1 + "px";
    footNoteSize = footNoteSize + 1 + "px";
    $(".heading").css({'font-size':headingSize});
    $(".content").css({'font-size':contentSize});
    $(".footNote").css({'font-size':footNoteSize});
  });
});
```

My problem is, how can I target all elements at once? Without creating many lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can loop through every `child` of `div` and change corresponding element using`$(this)`

**Working Demo**

```js
$(function() {
  $("#upSize").click(function() {
    $("div").children().each(function() {
      var size = parseInt($(this).css("font-size"));
      size = size + 1 + "px";
      $(this).css({
        'font-size': size
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.heading {
  font-size: 24px;
}
.content {
  font-size: 12px;
}
.footNote {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p class="heading">
    24px font
  </p>

  <p class="content">
    12px font
  </p>

  <span class="footNote">
    10px font
  </span>

  <button id="upSize">Larger</button>
```

**For Reference**

► [.children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/)

► [$(this)](http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/08/what-is-this)

Comment: Just so that he understands, this answer is iterating over all of the <p> tags instead of the individual elements.

Comment: @tempranova I am adding the description `:)`

Comment: hi @RinoRaj. thanks! that's useful. however, i just updated it with the HTML having different elements. Now, can I still check on each element to update the font size?

Comment: @thebeast22 I have updated my answer accordingly. Now it will check for all child elements under `div`

Comment: Wow. Amazing! Thanks! I did not know .children that's why. Thanks a lot! #jQueryaspirant

Comment: @thebeast22 I have updated my answer with reference. If you want to refer you can look that to get a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to increase font-size of all elements. But caveat lies in font-size inheritance, so I needed to [get all leaf nodes as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602431/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-get-leaf-nodes-with-jquery/76477424) with another caveat upon tags like *br* inside text

```
function addFontSize(fontAddition){
    $("*").filter(function() {
          return $(this).children('body,div,span').length == 0;
    }).each(function() {
        var size = parseInt($(this).css("font-size"));
        size = size + fontAddition + "px";
        $(this).css({
            'font-size': size
        });
    });
}
addFontSize(1);
```